# I want to show all result from an api

Tags: php, json, api, google-places-api

I'm working with google places API , and i showed content from the api but one by one like this

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.075971700000004,-0.7651981999999999&radius=5000&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyDxXV4Ka8yiDq1-UKzlzX-MUC8csfdN8y4');

$maps_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.075971700000004,-0.7651981999999999&radius=5000&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyDxXV4Ka8yiDq1-UKzlzX-MUC8csfdN8y4';
$maps_json = file_get_contents($maps_url);
$maps_array = json_decode($maps_json, true);
$lat = $maps_array['results'][1]['name'];
$lat2 = $maps_array['results'][2]['name'];
echo $lat;
echo "<br>";
echo $lat2;


?>
```

but i want to show all the result one time with a loop

Comment: Then use a loop. A foreach loop would be a good place to start.

Comment: `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($maps_array['results'] as $map) {
   echo $map['name'];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the results array in a `foreach` and make a loop from that. in that way u will get all the data instead of taking it 1 by 1. And for the numbers array u can add a ++ statement(not needed).

hope this helps. Good luck